# How to use Google Vault APIs to manage gmail retention rules?

Tags: api, google-workspace, retention

I'm implementing automation of our G-Suite operations. What's proper service/api to get/set gmail retention rules on org units? Google Vault API reference here https://developers.google.com/vault/quickstart/python covers few topics, but nothing about retention as I can tell. Any info is much appreciated.